# Angular - DomSanitizer security bypass - innerHTML styling Weird reloading effect

Tags: angular

I have an application where users are able to write documents. The content is delivered as **html** and may have "unsave content" in it. For example **iframes with youtube videos**.

I am outputting like this

```
<div [innerHtml]="getDocumentContentTrusted()"></div>
```

Components method

```
getMainContentTrusted(){
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.documentContent);
}
```

It kind of works. Everything is displayed correctly but as soon as for example a youtube-iframe is part of the documentContent i have a **sideeffect**. On any click anywhere in the application the **documentContent seems to be reloaded**.

Any hints on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for iframes we use bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl not bypassSecurityTrustHtml. in this case i think you need both.

try using these two filter in you case

1) safe url bypass filter 'safeUrl'

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeUrl' })
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

2) safe html bypass filter 'safeHtml'

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(value) {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

hope it will work

```
<div [innerHtml]="documentContent | safeHtml | safeUrl"></div>
```

Comment: You're right. It works perfect now! Although i had to change the order of the pipes ``<div [innerHtml]="documentContent | safeUrl | safeHtml"></div>``